# How to extract <li> from <ul using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text between `<li>` from this `id`. Whenever I run my code it outputs `None`. Do I have to make a variable for `<ul class = "qtyBreakUl"`?

HTML I am trying to extract: [image]

```
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.gogsg.com/2316358/Product/Wrisco_DECMSB24-1824').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')


test = soup.find(id = 'tdPriceBreak_DECMSB24-1824')

test1 = test.find('ul')

print(test1)
```

Comment: See the text you are trying to extract may be dynamic rendered using `JS` so `bs4` can't handle this type of data it will return only static data if possible can you share the URL!

Comment: Yes it's https://www.gogsg.com/2316358/Product/Wrisco_DECMSB24-1824

Answer (score 2):

The data is loaded dynamically. If you inspect your browser's Network tab, you will see the requests being made. You can reproduce the `GET` request with:

```
import requests


params = {
    "productIdList": "DECMSB24-1824,DECMSB24-2436,DECMSB24-2424,DECMSB24-1824,WRIW040-1218,WRIW040RAD34-1824,MDO1SR-12-48120-RAW"
}

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.gogsg.com/getPriceDetailPage.action", params=params
).json()


for data in response:
    print("{:<30} {}".format(data["partNumber"], data["price"]))
```

Output:

```
DECMSB24-1824                  11.32
DECMSB24-2436                  23.91
DECMSB24-2424                  15.02
DECMSB24-1824                  11.32
WRIW040-1218                   7.97
WRIW040RAD34-1824              17.78
MDO1SR-12-48120-RAW            94.98
```

Comment: Thank you! I just started web scraping so I'm gonna watch some tutorials regarding dynamic websites

Comment: How would you go about pulling the info from <ul class= "qtyBreakUl"? I want to have the price breakdown print with the productID/price

Comment: @Blutch I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Also, note you might want to use a tool called Selenium to scrape dynamic websites, since you can use the actual HTML with that